# Integrate WordPress Blogging to iphone App

Tags: iphone, ios, wordpress

I wanted to Integrate WordPress Blogging to iphone App, so is there any good tut for it .I googled it but could not get ..

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can control your wordpress made site from your iphone use this site :

http://ios.wordpress.org/

good luck